# Removing the second word in a string in Tcl

Tags: string, tcl

Lets say I have a string wordone wordtwo wordthree. I don't know what wordtwo will be but it needs to be removed whenever it exists. What can I do to remove it.

I attempted to use lreplace $string 1 1  "" but am getting the error " list element in braces followed by ... instead of space"

Comment: What is your source string? That error sounds like it isn't cleanly parsing into a list.

Comment: It's safer to use `split` on the input first to make sure you have a well-formed list before doing `lreplace`.

Answer (score 0):

If you treat your string as a list you can us [lreplace](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lreplace.html) to remove the 2nd word e.g.

```
set input_string "wordone wordtwo wordthree"
set result [lreplace $input_string 1 1]
```

Outputs:

```
wordone wordthree
```

Thinking a little more about this, it might be better to use [regsub](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/regsub.html) to match on whitespace, and extract the 2nd word. This should work:

```
    set input_string "wordone wordtwo wordthree"
    regsub {^(\S+)\s+\S+} $input_string {\1} result
    puts $result ;# wordone wordthree
```

Comment: I like the `regsub`, but putting `\s*` before the `\S+` in the parentheses will make it work with leading whitespace too.